# Load entire html page in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I need to store in a str variable an entire html page. 
I'm doing this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = my_url
response = requests.get(url)
page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))
```

This works but the page in my_url is not "complete". It is a website in which going to the end, new things will load, and i need all the page, not only the main visible part.

Is there a way to load the entire page and then store it?

I also tried to load the page manually and then looking at the source code, but the final part of the page is still not visible.

Alternatively, all I want from my_url page are all the links inside it, and all of them are like:

```
my_url/something/first-post
my_url/something/second-post
```

Is there a way to find all the links in another way? So, all the possible url that starts with "my_url/something/"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) and then scroll down with it to get entire the page.

as I know `requests` can't handle dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

For the alternative option, you can find the `<a> tags` via `find_all`

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
```

to get all starting with you can use the following

```
result = [link for link  in links if link.startswith('my_url/something/')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not see the hide content (the one that emerge when going down into the page)

Comment: If it is dynamically loaded there will be no way around it then simulating the action that causes it to be loaded via Selenium in example. You could still use the above then to find the links that start with a specific string.